# I am applying for a new PhD position. However I'm already enrolled at one institute for the past one year. How do I explain my drop out?

Tags: phd, research-process, time-off

So I enrolled at a reputed Research Institute in Taiwan one year ago, just after my Master's. However, the course work and research conducted here was not as I expected it to be. I tackled it well but the professors keep rejecting me after working for almost a month in their labs saying they can't accommodate me.

Since it has been a year and I don't have any lab, they are revoking my stipend. Being an international student I can't afford the living cost here.
Now I am applying to another university in the same city.

How do I explain my one year PhD drop out in my applications. I fear I should not lie since it's the same city and the professors might find out sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a clean breast of the situation. Let the new one be told regarding the non-availability of accommodation in the lab. And hope for the best.